# How can I make *only* the posts wider?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

In my [Tumblr blog](http://blog.omarayoub.com/), the positions of the different elements are great as is, except for the posts themselves. Right now, the post symbols (the little black and white icons to the left of the post titles) are aligned with the main logo above them. What I want to do is make the posts (as well as the other stuff like the page-number tabs at the top and bottom of the page) wider, thus shifting the symbols further to the left and aligning the left edge of the posts with the main logo above them.

To see what I mean, check out the below image of the desired outcome (which you can compare to the current design).

[image]

How do I go about doing these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit screen.css and do changes based on my comments:

```
.post, .strip {
clear: both;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 0 0 100px;//change this to 20px 0 0 0;
width: 500px; //width to 600px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.body {
width: 500px; //width to 600px;
}
.post a.icon {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 20px; 
left: 0; // this to -100px;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
}
```

Also add this to make panel with pages at the top wider:

```
#page-strip {
position: absolute;
left: 100px; //to 0px;
top: 13px;
width: 400px; // to 600px;
height: 5px;
background: #e5e5e5;
-webkit-border-radius: 2.5px;
-moz-border-radius: 2.5px;
border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Owl, you're amazing. A minor glitch, the post icons are overlapping the post titles. How can I fix that?

Comment: I know I'm pushing it now, but how can I also make the stream of likes on the right (the column of "liked" posts on the right side of the blog) go down all the way to the bottom instead of stopping all of a sudden? Thanks again Owl!

Comment: No problem Omar. I like your blog :) Post icons overlapping because you forgot about "px" in ".post a.icon{}" styles. Change it to "-100px"

Comment: I cant answer to your second question. This problem is more related to your CMS than CSS. You can try add more "like items" but i'm just guessing now. Also worth to note that you can embed youtube content with 600px wide iframes.

Comment: Thanks a million Owl. You're the best!

Comment: I'm glad you like my blog :)

Comment: Good you like it. You can do something for me as well - accept my answer as corrected so i get some points :) thanks